# JavaScript Regex formatted on multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a really complex JavaScript replace regex function and I am wondering is there a way to format the regex code on multiple lines like this:

```
/
(
    ([0-9]{1,2})
    (\/|\.)
    ([0-9]{1,2})
    (\/|\.)
    ([0-9]{2,4})\s
)?
([0-9]{1,2})
:
([0-9]{1,2})
(
    (:|\s)
    ([0-9]{1,2})
)?
/ig
```

Also I'd like to ask if there is another way to format regex so it's easier to read.

Comment: Regex is pretty much write-only. The best solution might be to put that along with explanations in a comment above the actual regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have support for the `/x` flag (which allows spaces and comments), but you can split your expression over multiple lines using strings. For example:

```
var re = new RegExp(
     "foo" +
     "bar" +
     "baz",
     "ig");
```

Of course this has the disadvantage of regular string quoting of regex (double escapes).

You could also use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) with its `(?x)` flag, but you are still limited by the regular JS string quoting.

Comment: Never thought about such solution. Looks interesting!

Comment: Indeed when I have "\" character for escaping it has to be double: `"\\s" + "([0-9])"`

Answer (score 1):

```
myPatter = new RegExp(
     '([0-9]{1,2})'   +
     '.... a new line' +
     '... anotherline'
);
```

Comment: @IvanDokov Qtax had a better idea, I stupidly made it too complex with the array and join! (late in the day here)